# Components are not rendered but the URL changes after updating to React-Router-DOM v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have updated to `react-router-dom` version 6 and the URL I see that it's updated but then the components are not rendered. Also when I refresh the page the component is still not rendering.

I have this code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout/>} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Authenticate/>}>
          <Route index element={<Analysis />} />
          <Route path='/analysis' element={<Analysis />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>} />
          .....
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

const rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootNode)
```

The only component that it does render is the `<Authenticate/>` component. Inside this component when I am changing routes I have this code implemented

```js
handleClick = e => {
  console.log('e is :', e.key)
  if (e.key !== '/logout') {
    history.push(e.key)
  }
}
```

Do I have something wrong on my implementation or something else?

I am using:

```json
"react-router-dom": "^6.22.1",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"history": "^5.3.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue(s)

The [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router) component doesn't consume any `history` prop

> ```
> declare function BrowserRouter(
>   props: BrowserRouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface BrowserRouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   future?: FutureConfig;
>   window?: Window;
> }
> ```

so the likely issue here is that your custom `history` reference is effecting navigation actions *outside* the `BrowserRouter` component's scope. In other words, the router is completely unaware of them and doesn't react to the external URL changes.

Because `Authenticate` is a layout route component, it ***must*** render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render out their `element` content when the URL path is matched. Ensure this is the case.

## Solution

### Using `BrowserRouter` (Preferred)

Use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook and `navigate` function to effect navigation actions. Update `Authenticate` and any other routed component to use the `useNavigate` hook.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Authenticate = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  handleClick = e => {
    if (e.key !== '/logout') {
      navigate(e.key); // <-- issue PUSH action
    }
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    ...
  );
};
```

### Using `HistoryRouter` and custom `history` object

Import and use the *undocumented* [`HistoryRouter`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/13ac1b6c5cc2c3f99629bed6ed0ccc8542de0d94/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L854-L898). Create and export your `history` object separately so all components reference ***the same*** history reference.

Example:

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

```
import {
  unstable_HistoryRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './path/to/history';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout/>} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Authenticate/>}>
          <Route index element={<Analysis />} />
          <Route path='/analysis' element={<Analysis />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>} />
          .....
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Authenticate.jsx

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './path/to/history';

const Authenticate = () => {
  ...

  handleClick = e => {
    if (e.key !== '/logout') {
      history.push(e.key); // <-- issue PUSH action
    }
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    ...
  );
};
```

Only use this version if you *really* have a need for the external custom `history` object, e.g. you are connecting your router to a Redux store or similar, otherwise, the first option is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for you response, one problem that i have is that i am using class components. If i downgrade the react-router-dom and history maybe it's better? And apply your recommendations? What do you think ? Also i tried the 2nd solution and apply the <Outlet/> component but i am loosing my css style and also i have to refresh the page to load the new page

Comment: @burrito I'd suggest updating your code from React Class components to React function components since Class components have effectively been deprecated since React hooks were released in [React 16.8 from February 2019](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html). In the meantime you could implement your own [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) Higher Order Component to inject `location`, `navigate`, and `params` props.

Comment: @burrito For addressing any issues specific to routing/navigation with regards to any app styling/CSS this would likely require a separate Stackoverflow post.

Comment: it's a big rework to update from class components to functional, but you are right this has to be done. But for now i have did the one with `withRouter` that you mention and works by adding also the `<Outlet />` component as you also mentioned on your answer. So thank you! The only things that remains is the problem with css and the jsx after adding the `<Outlet />`